# Not able to login through mysql database in Openshift

Tags: java, mysql, openshift

I have created a java login application with mysql database and deployed it on OpenShift. 
URL: http://passwordbucket-king003.rhcloud.com/SimpleLoginTest/
while trying to running its simply showing a blank page with URL-http://passwordbucket-king003.rhcloud.com/SimpleLoginTest/loginservlet .But ideally  it should show the home page. Here is my database connection file, please let me know that where I wrong?

package database;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseConnection 
{
//    private final String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logindemo";
//    private final String username = "root";
//    private final String password = "root";

    private final String OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT = "3306";
    private final String OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST= "127.3.110.129";
    private final String OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD= "root";
    private final String OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME= "root";
    private final String OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL= "jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/logindemo";

    public Connection con = null;    

    public Connection openConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
//            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println(getClass().getClass()+" = " +ex.toString());
        }
        return con;        
    }

    public void closeConnection() throws SQLException
    {
        if(!con.isClosed()){
            con.close();        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, on OpenShift your application should be deployed as ROOT.war and there should be content at the "/" context.

Second, if you want to read and use environment variables, you should use System.getenv(). For example:

```
private final String OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST);
```

Your connection URL should also contain the credentials given to you when you created the database.

The database name is probably "passwordbucket" the same as your application name.

In stead of using a jdbc connection you should consider using the JNDI datasource that comes preconfigured on OpenShift. Please check the documentation. You disd not specify the container type you are using.

Comment: Thanks for Help. Now I am able to login into the applicaation but now I am getting the in some another page. Could you please help me on that also.        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512777/java-getting-error-on-openshift-but-working-fine-on-localhost